# History of odds making in sports betting

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, math-history

Can anyone provide a reference to the history of odds making in sports betting? In many cases, certain odds are set and then adjusted as people make bets. However, I am having difficulty tracing the history of this sort of sports betting model. Any reference to sports betting and odd making from a historical or modern perspective would be quite useful.

Thank you in advance and please ask me to clarify if my question is not clear.

Comment: Thompson, William (2001). Gambling in America--An Encyclopedia of History, Issues, and Society. Also see, http://casinodetroit.net/casjan02.html

Comment: @Amzoti Thank you, I will look into those.

Comment: You are very welcome. I think those three books will contain all the references needed for the history from ancient to present day. One of them even includes the back-door names of players.